# Can we re-trigger the gitlab pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-ci

After creating merge request in GitLab, merge request got failed and jenkins has deleted the failed job logs due to retention period defined under jenkins job. Now, i want to re-trigger that specific merge request only from gitlab so that it will trigger the merge request job  in jenkins. Is it possible ? If yes, how can i do the same ?

P.S. There is a pipeline defined from Gitlab to Jenkins. Whenever a merge request get creates in gitlab, it triggers the Jenkins Merge Request job which merge the specific changes to the git master branch.

Comment: Do you want to trigger the gitlab pipelines or the jenkins pipelines? Do you have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file defined with a job that triggers jenkins?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can retrigger the Gitlab Pipelines!
There are two options available:

1. Use the UI
2. Use the [Gitlab Api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)

## Using the UI

1. Within in your project go to `CI / CD`: `https://gitlab.com/{user/organization}/{project}/pipelines`
2. Then click on the green button `Run Pipeline`
3. Select the branch you made the merge request for.
4. Hit the `Create Pipeline` button.

This will create and run a gitlab pipeline.

## Using the API

1. Make sure you have a [token](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens) available which can use the Gitlab API.
2. Make a **POST** call to `gitlab.com/projects/:id/trigger/pipeline`

   1. You can run a curl command to do this
   2. ```
      curl -X POST -F token=TOKEN -F ref=BRANCHNAME https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/7471909/trigger/pipeline
      ```

If you want to trigger a [build manually](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) in Jenkins you can also make use of an api in combination with a parameterized build:

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build --user USER:TOKEN  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"branch", "value":"master"}]}'
```

The parameter will be the branch to build; eg the branch for your merge request.

Comment: If you're able to build the link for the user, you can create a link to `{project url}/pipelines/new?ref={branch}`, so the user just needs to click "Run Pipeline" to trigger the pipeline for the branch.

Comment: Your suggestion is to re-trigger a branch pipeline, while the questions asks about MR pipeline. The two are not (always) the same.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to the merge request page.
2. In the tabs section (next to Overview), Go to the `Pipelines` tab.
3. Click on the button `Run pipeline`.

Comment: Our (up to date) instance has no such button. Is it maybe only present if no pipeline was automatically created ? All our commits trigger pipelines, so all MRs already have at least one for us. No button is visible to run another one.